# Composer not finding privately hosted package

Tags: php, git, composer-php, bitbucket

So, composer search works and does return the package with its description. Additionally, it prompts me for authentication to get that information. The problem is when I run composer info tradedefender/xignite-options-reader it gives me a Package not found error. Same problem with attempting to install the package. Here is my application's composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "repositories": [
      {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://jrgilman@bitbucket.org/tradedefender/xignite-options-reader.git"
      }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

Here is my package's composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "tradedefender/xignite-options-reader",
    "version": "master",
    "description": "Reads options data from Xignite using PHP/Python",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Jacob Ray Gilman",
            "email": "jacob.r.gilman@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {},
    "autoload": {
      "psr-4": {
        "TradeDefender\\XigniteOptionsReader\\": "/src/php"
      }
    }
}
```

Here is the issue from the CLI:

```
jacob@jacob-MS-7693:~/Documents/test-env$ composer search tradedefender
    Authentication required (bitbucket.org):
      Username: XXXXXXXX@XXXXXXXX
      Password: 
Do you want to store credentials for bitbucket.org in /home/jacob/.composer/auth.json ? [Yn] n
tradedefender/xignite-options-reader Reads options data from Xignite using PHP/Python
jacob@jacob-MS-7693:~/Documents/test-env$ composer info tradedefender/xignite-options-reader


  [InvalidArgumentException]                              
  Package tradedefender/xignite-options-reader not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My version of Composer includes the following output from `composer info --help`:

> ```
> -i, --installed
>     List installed packages only (enabled by default, only present for BC).
> ```

It looks like `composer info` just looks at installed packages by default. Adding either the `--all` flag (to show installed and available packages) or `-a` / `--available` flag (to show just available packages) should make this work:

```
composer info --all tradedefender/xignite-options-reader
```

It has nothing to do with the repository being private.